# Display cognito username as text

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I feel like this should be a very easy task, but I cannot find any examples of this and have tried plenty of ways to do this myself. I am trying to simply call `Auth.currentSession()` to retrieve the username of a cognito user in my React Native application. So far, this code does not allow the app to load, I just get a blank screen. Most solutions I've tried either result in blank screen or simply not displaying anything.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  getUsername = async () => {
    try {
      let info = await Auth.currentSession()
      let userName = info.idToken.payload['cognito:username']
      return userName
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
  
  render() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Text>{this.getUsername()}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}}

export default HomeScreen;
```

The following code below does not display anything:

```
  render() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Text>{this.getUsername}</Text> // or {getUsername} or {getUsername()}
    </View>
  );
}}
```

I've also tried this:

```
function Homescreen() {

   async function getUsername() {
    try {
      let info = await Auth.currentSession()
      let userName = info.idToken.payload['cognito:username']
      return userName
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
  
  render() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Text>{this.getUsername()}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}}
```

I should warn that this is my first time coding JS so I might be missing something very obvious and apologize for that in advance. Please help, thanks!

*Update*

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {name:''}
  }
  
  componentDidMount(){
    getUsername()
  }
  
  getUsername = async () => {
    try {
      let info = await Auth.currentSession()
      let userName = info.idToken.payload['cognito:username']
      this.setState({name: userName})
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  };

  render() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Text>{this.state.name}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}}
```

Yields:

[image: error]

Comment: How did you signin? Do u see the user in aws cognito "user and groups" tab.

Comment: I signed in by using the withAuthenticator HOC, then I try to create the async function to fetch the username and it fetches nothing. I've inspected the JWT and there IS in fact a string present but just can't get it to display :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a state to update and display in the `render` method

```
constructor(){
  this.state = {name: ""}
}

componentDidMount(){
  getUsername()
}

getUsername = async () => {
  try {
    let info = await Auth.currentSession()
    let userName = info.idToken.payload['cognito:username']
    this.setState({name: userName })
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

and update the return

```
<Text>{this.state.name}</Text>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot set property 'state' of undefined` when running this code though

Comment: just updated question with your code reflected and the consequent error, thanks a bunch for the help!

Comment: In your constructor, you'll want to pass in "props" as a parameter and then call "super(props)"

Comment: It compiles with `super(props)` but still not getting any username displayed in the `<Text>{this.state.name}</Text>` field